# How to load fonts same at the time of page loading using Adobe Typekit Js Code

Tags: javascript, adobe, toolkit

I need help. I need to load font at the time of my page loading.

please check my code below :

```
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/itz7ece.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>
```

By using the above code i can not load font. Please help me.